# Changing the color of collapsingToolbarLayout on scroll

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

So i have run into a problem which i cant find the solution of.I have made a small clip of the problem. 
[Video](http://sendvid.com/x0vlypdl)

What i want is that as soon as i scroll the `collapsingToolbarLayout` the color should start changing to the toolbar color as it happens in facebook app. As you can see it starts after when it cover 3/4 height of the `collapsingToolbarLayout`.

**XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="56dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:background="#200000" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Appreciate any help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` has an attribute called `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger`

> Specifies the amount of visible height in pixels used to define when to trigger a scrim visibility change.

Since your app bar has a height of 280dp, setting `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="240dp"` should work.

I can't remember if that's from the top or from the bottom, so if that makes it change really late, try `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="20dp"`.  Anyhow, you should be able to tweak that value to get the look you want.